# how to send extra data in request?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I want to send itemId in http request. how to do it and what will I see on server req?

here is request:

```
var fd = new FormData();
var itemId = scope.vm.item._id;

fd.append('file', scope.files[0]);
$http.post('http://localhost:8090/file-upload', fd, {
   transformRequest: angular.identity,
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': undefined
   }
});
```

server

```
 app.post('/file-upload', function(req, res, next) {
console.log("received file");
var pathFile = ' ';
var wId = "itemId";

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads/attachments');
        pathFile = file.originalname;
    },
    filename: function (req, file,itemId, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
        console.log(itemId);

    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).single('file');
upload(req,res,function(err) {

    if(err) {
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }

    //save file path in work items doc.attachments
    var path = './uploads/attachments/'+pathFile;

res.end("File is uploaded");
});
```

serve code added. How to get itemId on server side?

Comment: what about `fd.itemId = itemId`?

Comment: addeded backend

Comment: You can just append it to the form data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a couple a ways you could do it, you could just set the params property in your post options and pass in an object with id as a property.

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    var itemId = scope.vm.item._id;

    fd.append('file', scope.files[0]);
    $http.post('http://localhost:8090/file-upload', fd, {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                    params: {id: itemId}

                });
```

Comment: used but nothing got in params:But got in querry.thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can append JSON string to the FromData object like below.

**fd.append('params', JSON.stringify({itemId: itemId}));**

On the server side, you will get JSON string in params key.

Answer (score 0):

simple add your parameters in params and pass your all the parameters.

```
 $http.post('http://localhost:8090/file-upload', fd, {
                 transformRequest: angular.identity,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                        params: {id: scope.vm.item._id}

                    });
```

hope this works for you.